# Error when page loads, but before anything is executed

Tags: javascript

When I open my local host, I am getting the following error
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from //at getData ((index):60)`

Which is pointing to these lines of code

```
 const response = await fetch(url, {
```

&

```
  getData(`/${url}`)
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error when I load the page, as should I only get something like this when I search for something?

This is the larger block of code I am referring to:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); getData(); })

const form = document.getElementById('Submit')
var formResult = new FormData(form);
const url = '/' + encodeURIComponent(formResult.get("search")); 

async function getData(url = '', data = {}) {
    
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    return response.json();
  }

  getData(`/${url}`)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

---

Edit based on comments:
Front end:

```
const form = document.getElementById('Submit')
var formResult = new FormData(form);
const url = '/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(formResult.get("search")); 

async function getData(url = '', data = {}) {

const response = await fetch(url) {
method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  .then(response =>{
   console.log(response)
            })
  .catch(err=>{
   console.error(err)
           })
```

Portion of my express Server:

```
const url = req.body
let urlDecoded = decodeURIComponent(url.url)
console.log(url, urlDecoded)


app.use(express.static("Public"));

app.post('/:url', async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.url);
  try {
    await whoisanalyzer.init();
    const site = await whoisanalyzer.open(decodeURIComponent(req.query.url));
    const data = await site.analyze();

    return res.status(200).json(data);

  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    return res.status(500).json({ message : "Oops." });
    
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the getData() function because of the parameter of it getData(url=' ')
The getData() function replace url with the parameter not with the variable so the fetch url is gonna be
Fetch(" ", { ....})
You have to define the url or the parameter with anther name

You also call the function inside the same function in

```
getData(`/${url}`)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

That is wrong because the function will never end

Comment: Can you provide an answer as to how you would adjust? How can I replace the parameter with the variable? On my backend I am using req.url.params.

Comment: I updated the post with relevent portion of my backend. Should I not be using the parameter as I am using url params?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly like that

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', async function(e) { 

e.preventDefault();

const form = document.getElementById('Submit')
var formResult = new FormData(form);
const url = '/' + encodeURIComponent(formResult.get("search")); 


    
  const response = await fetch(url)
  .then(response =>{
   console.log(response)
            })
  .catch(err=>{
   cosnole.error(err)
           })
```

Comment: Doing that will remove my GET request however... hoping you can provide some clarity

Comment: why that will remove your GET request ? it does the GET request with the url you defined it .  also your url can be like that <<url = '/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(formResult.get("search")); >> and in then in the back end put it as `req.query.url` this is better

Comment: also please notice if you want to send an information like json data or files or any kind of data ,you have to use POST request because GET request will never do that , so change this request to POST request and send the form data to the back end and do the logic on it there then redirect to any page

Comment: Just made changes to post based on your comments. Is that what you mean?

Comment: can you tell me what do you try to do so i can help you

Comment: To summarize, I am trying to submit a URL on the front end, to return a response from my express backend

Comment: To be specific, the result would be the country and city where the url is registered

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take a url and send it to the back end and  your front end code is like this

```
<form action="POST">

    <input type="text" name="url">
    <input type="submit" value="press">
</form>
```

so your the code in your js file is gonna be like this below :-

```
        const form = document.querySelector('form')
    form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let urlIN = form.url.value
        let url = encodeURIComponent(urlIN)
        console.log(url)
        const data = await fetch('/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    url: url
                })

            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                console.log('get')
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
            })
    })
```

and i tested it and it's working , i could send the url of this page and decoded it and i printed it in my console like that

my back end code

```
    const url = req.body
let urlDecoded = decodeURIComponent(url.url)
console.log(url, urlDecoded)
```

and the result is

> {
> url: 'https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F65757144%2Ferror-when-page-loads-but-before-anything-is-executed%2F65760895%3Fnoredirect%3D1%23comment116273379_65760895'
> }

[Error when page loads, but before anything is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757144/error-when-page-loads-but-before-anything-is-executed/65760895?noredirect=1#comment116273379_65760895)

Comment: Thanks for this! But I am trying to return results from my backend, specifically the country and city. Not the url encoded... apologies if I had caused any confusion...

Comment: yes , i know that but what i'm tring to say is that you can send the url to the back end like that  and then you can do what ever you want such console it  or put it in your functions to get the city and the country and then after that you can redirect to any page

Comment: Okay I will try this out. You may hear from me again... thanks so much!! You may hear from me again :)

Comment: Running my node server gives me the error that req is not defined. I have also updated the post to show what my current server looks like

Comment: get in here https://app.codingrooms.com/w/ogfOgPwtcgtr

Comment: I am unable to type

Comment: make a new coding room and send me the link